# Как лучше всего реализовать yii2 -> REST API -> React js?

Tags: php, yii2, reactjs, api, rest

Как лучше всего реализовать yii2 -> REST API -> React js?

Больше всего интересует, как сделать REST API -> React js
Более менее понял, как сделать yii2 -> REST

Вообще это можно сделать или нужен еще какой то инструмент?

Comment: Есть функция fetch

Comment: @Alex78191 fetch это метод js?

Comment: Так в гайдах же есть описание создания REST API, что с ним не так?

Comment: @ОлегБеляй конечно.